# How to do reverse parallax for background image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I saw this parallax animation on [Far Cry 6 website](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-gb/game/far-cry/far-cry-6) and wanted to recreate it in Flutter. I read the docs and watched some tutorials but I am not able to achieve this design accurately. I want to make a mobile version like the website shows on Mobile Browser like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDuwM.jpg

The image needs to be on top of one another and when I scroll, the bottom image should come from bottom to top in a reversed manner as the website. I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Please tell me how I can achieve this?

My Code -

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Material(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.network(
              "https://staticctf.akamaized.net/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/1mP5aHQYJI5xw08eD2eV0W/7bc890d58c6bcf5efbe8713f147828ae/banner-webasset.jpg",
              height: height,
              // width: width,
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: height),
                  Image.network(
                    "https://staticctf.akamaized.net/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/7ad5MGeYDCekqMiS5qRZuK/1005c73ea409e895058d4273d93dcb1a/banner-background_alt.jpg",
                    height: height,
                    width: width,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

basic idea is to use `ScrollMetrics` from `ScrollNotification` :

parallax.dart:

```
class Parallax extends StatefulWidget {
  const Parallax({Key? key, required this.childreen}) : super(key: key);
  final List<Widget> childreen;

  @override
  State<Parallax> createState() => _ParallaxState();
}

class _ParallaxState extends State<Parallax> {
  late double _pixel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _pixel = 0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (notif) {
        setState(() {
          _pixel = notif.metrics.pixels;
        });
        return true;
      },
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: List.generate(
              widget.childreen.length,
              (index) => _ParalaxChild(
                  index: index,
                  pixel: _pixel,
                  childreenLenght: widget.childreen.length,
                  child: widget.childreen[index])),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ParalaxChild extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final Widget child;
  final double pixel;
  final int childreenLenght;
  const _ParalaxChild(
      {Key? key,
      required this.child,
      required this.index,
      required this.pixel,
      required this.childreenLenght})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRect(
      child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
              FractionalTranslation(
                  translation: Offset(0.0, -_calculateParallax(context)),
                  child: child),
              const Positioned(
                  bottom: 200,
                  right: 20,
                  child: Text(
                    "Parallax",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
              const Positioned(
                  bottom: 12,
                  right: 20,
                  left: 20,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  double _calculateParallax(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double pageHeight = height * index;
    final double childPosition = (pageHeight - pixel) / height;
    return childPosition.isNaN ? 0.0 : childPosition;
  }
}
```

use it or you can customize :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Parallax(childreen: [
        Image.network(
          "https://staticctf.akamaized.net/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/1mP5aHQYJI5xw08eD2eV0W/7bc890d58c6bcf5efbe8713f147828ae/banner-webasset.jpg",
          height: height,
          // width: width,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
        Image.network(
          "https://staticctf.akamaized.net/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/7ad5MGeYDCekqMiS5qRZuK/1005c73ea409e895058d4273d93dcb1a/banner-background_alt.jpg",
          height: height,
          width: width,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
        Image.network(
          "https://staticctf.akamaized.net/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/1mP5aHQYJI5xw08eD2eV0W/7bc890d58c6bcf5efbe8713f147828ae/banner-webasset.jpg",
          height: height,
          // width: width,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
        Image.network(
          "https://staticctf.akamaized.net/J3yJr34U2pZ2Ieem48Dwy9uqj5PNUQTn/7ad5MGeYDCekqMiS5qRZuK/1005c73ea409e895058d4273d93dcb1a/banner-background_alt.jpg",
          height: height,
          width: width,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

**edit**
For torn effect :

[image]

i create clipper for your reference you can always customize later:

```
class TornEffect extends CustomClipper<Path>{
  ///how much the torn effect will be
  final int intensity;

  TornEffect({required this.intensity});

  @override
  ui.Path getClip(ui.Size size) {

    var path = Path();
    //make sure path on left top corner
    path.moveTo(0.0, 0.0);

    var random = math.Random();
    
    //to prevent blankSpace, move y to top (must always negative):
    double ybase = -20.0;

    //top:
    double topProgress = 0.0;
    while(topProgress < size.width){
      bool curve = random.nextBool();
      if(curve){
        
        double cpx = topProgress + random.nextInt(intensity) * 0.5 * negativePositive();
        double cpy = ybase + (random.nextInt(intensity) * 0.25 * negativePositive());

        double x = topProgress + random.nextInt(intensity)* 1.0 * negativePositive();
        double y = ybase + (random.nextInt(intensity) * 0.5 * negativePositive());

        path.quadraticBezierTo(
            cpx,
            cpy,
            x,
            y
        );
        topProgress += x.abs();
      }
      else {
        
        double x = topProgress + random.nextInt(intensity) * 1.0 * negativePositive();
        double y = ybase + (random.nextInt(intensity) * 0.5 * negativePositive());
        path.lineTo(x, y);
        topProgress += x.abs();
      }
    }
    //make sure top right corner got shape
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);

    // line to bottom right corner
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    // you can build bottom rip effect later:
    //double bottomProgress = 0.0;
    //while(){}

    // bottom left
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);

    //close it with another line
    path.close();
    return path;

  }

  double negativePositive(){
    var random = math.Random();
    bool negativePositive = random.nextBool();
    double result = negativePositive ? 1.0: -1.0;
    return result;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<ui.Path> oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    //return this != oldClipper;
    // return false for performance, or rebuilt every scroll
    return false;
  }

}
```

on parallax.dart:

```
return ClipPath(
      clipper: TornEffect(intensity: 21),
      child: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: [
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer. Can you also tell me how to move the image to the left or right, I wish to keep the poster in the center in the mobile version and I am not able to move the pic around with Positioned widget. How can I do it?

Comment: sure, `Image.Network()` has alignment property, you can adjust the image you want before render it in paralax widget, for example : give it - x value it will move to the right : `Aligment(-0.5 , 0.0)` , its based on how you fit the box, if you use `BoxFit.fitHeight` you cant align y property because no more space on image it self. you can simply use Aligment.Center.  i can assist you more but i need some visual how you want image will be rendered, you can even animate the text too.

Comment: Thank you, I achieved the exact design I wanted using the Alignment property. Can you please also let me know how I can get a torn page like design at the bottom of the pic while scrolling like its on the website. I think CustomPainter can help me achieve that design but I am not able to figure out how and where to apply it.

Comment: you notice i use ClipRect as it parent of Stack? its because the background image actually overlapping each other in same positon, when user scroll, they are scroll the `ClipRect` and `SizeBox` as frame or maybe camera, that how parallax effect work in first place, to make a torn effect you can use `ClipPath`, with that you can use `CustomClipper<Path>` class to draw your custom path. i am not fluent in english i hope you get it what i mean

Comment: maybe after you clip it like torn effect you get some blank space between image, then there is several ways to fix it, i update the code later, away from computer right now, please wait

Comment: i edit the answer hope its help, cheers happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much for updating the answer, just one more question, what will be the import for `ui.Path` in @override method?

Comment: @MarufHassan its import dart.ui as ui, something like that but i think its not necessary, just to make sure get correct path class

Comment: I have been trying to perfect the design with the other images and I have found varying degree of success in smaller screens but in bigger screen, the images leave some space at the bottom. If you can have a look at my repo or if it would be ok with you, then can we have a small chat on Linkedin?
My Repo - https://github.com/zyllus17/far_cry_6_parallax
Linkedin - https://www.linkedin.com/in/maruf-hassan/

Comment: if you want to advance to low level api, maybe its time to render it directly at `custom painter`, with that way the code have a logic determine what part of image should be rendered, scale need and how to fit it in canvas size. `drawAtlas` mehod is the key.

Comment: Custom painter can accept a listenable as super value, this more performant since we dont need to use setState and rebuild the widget tree .if i have time i will look at it, but currently i am pretty busy right know, sorry